# Как сделать два разных задних фона на сайт для смартфонов и ПК?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, media-queries

Всем привет, я новичок в сайтостроении, заканчиваю свой первый сайт, мне осталось только отобразить на главной странице фон с афишей открытия сайта, с ссылкой на бота в телеграм.

Заказчик скинул два фона, один для ПК 1920 х 1080, а второй для мобилок, не помню точное разрешение.

На ПК все отобразил, но не знаю как отобразить второй фон только на смартах, надеюсь на вашу помощь, вот ссылки на обе картинки

http://img.uztor.pw/img/2020-08/15/dcmehk1fq4k2qrso4pw7shmv9.jpg http://img.uztor.pw/img/2020-08/14/b1z1f9foy9yc5ukmeokqsat5b.jpg

Мой код:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://img.uztor.pw/img/2020-08/14/b1z1f9foy9yc5ukmeokqsat5b.jpg)
}

.bglink {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  text-indent: -5000em;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<a class="bglink" href="https://t.me/ProMallBot"> </a>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: смотри CSS @media screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого будет достаточно создать [@media-правило](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@media), которое будет "говорить" браузеру какую картинку следует отображать отталкиваясь от ширины viewport'a:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://img.uztor.pw/img/2020-08/14/b1z1f9foy9yc5ukmeokqsat5b.jpg")
}

.bglink {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-indent: -5000em;
  z-index: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("http://img.uztor.pw/img/2020-08/15/dcmehk1fq4k2qrso4pw7shmv9.jpg")
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="bglink" href="https://t.me/ProMallBot"></a>
<div class="container"></div>
```

*Измените размер (max-width: 600px) на тот который Вам нужен.*